# Does Silverlight run on the Client

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I would like to know if silverlight run on the client like javascript. Silverlight will be doing alot of work and I want to make sure it all runs on the client.

How do i know if a button click goes back to the server or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Silverlight runs in the browser.  The compiled code gets downloaded to the browser in a .XAP file and then runs locally.  A button click would not cause anything to happen on the server unless you actually wrote code to call a service.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Silverlight apps are downloaded and run on client, just like flash and javascript. You have total control for users interactions being sent to the server or not, so it depends on how you want your application to behave.